# error TS2304: cannot find name 'FB' in angular 6 FB login

Tags: angular, facebook, facebook-login

i am trying to use facebook api with angular 6 by firing an click event. i understand window.fbAsyncInit which loads the sdk first and then inside that i can use FB.login which runs automatically,

but i want to call a function from component html after window.fbAsyncInit.

indx.html  that will automatically call fb login on load that i dont want

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'my-app-id',
      cookie     : true,
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v3.1'
    });
    FB.AppEvents.logPageView();

    //i can do this instead that will call fb login automatically, bt i want a click event from component.html file

    FB.login(function(response) {
      console.log(response); //here i am getting response automatially that i dont want, i want to fire a click event 
    });
}

(function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

component.html here i want to call fb.login from click event inside function

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-facebook" (click) = "facebookLogin();">Facebook Login</button>
```

component.ts calling this function but not getting initialize after fbAsyncInit in index.html

```
   facebookLogin(){
        FB.login((response)=>
        {
          console.log('submitLogin',response);
            if (response.authResponse)
            {
                //login success
                //login success code here
                //redirect to home page
            }else{
               console.log('User login failed');
            }
        });

    }
```

i want to call this function on click inside fbAsyncinit in index.html without getting that error. can you please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Declare after imports.

<..imports...>

declare var FB;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  ...
})